# Protect uploaded .svg files with .htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, svg

I'm allowing .svg uploads and looking for a way to protect them from injections with .htaccess file in specific location.

What is the best practice if I want to minimize the risk of having .svg files uploaded to my public_html/public/uploads folder?

Edit: the point is to be able to publicly view .svg, but somehow protect them from being edited.

Comment: If external users can place files in your uploads folder, I don't think `.htaccess` is the place to secure it, but rather folder permissions. I might be wrong tho, let's see what others say :)

Comment: How are you managing ".svg uploads"? What type of "injections" are you wanting to protect them against? "minimize the risk of having .svg files uploaded" - that's different to protecting the .svg files themselves (as would seem to be implied in the first sentence)? How are these `.svg` files ultimately used? Presumably they need to be publicly readable in order to be used in client-side HTML?

Comment: @MrWhite uploads are managed via media library (forms). I'm looking to protect the .svg files against any type of JS injection (modification of files). The files are used as you described - publicly readable via HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with .htaccess :

```
<FilesMatch "\.svg$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Although this blocks all client-side access to these files. I wonder what the point of uploading the files if they can't be viewed publicly?

Comment: Yeah, if .svg can't be viewed publicly than there is no point. Any other ideas?